# Given the current time and deadline time represented by the variables above, determine if an assignment is still eligible for submission

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

An assignment is eligible if the time represented by current_hour, current_minute, and current_section is before the time represented by due_hour, due_minute, and due_section. Section refers to AM/PM.

I am new to programming and am working on the following problem. I am able to solve for all test cases except for the instance where the current time is 12:37 AM and due time is 9:00 AM.

When I try it in my code it returns "False" instead of "True" even though when I go through it myself I don't see how it returns "False" instead of "True" with the criteria I outlined in my code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
if current_section == "PM" and current_hour != 12:
    current_hour += 12

if due_section == "PM" and due_hour != 12:
    due_hour += 12

if current_section == "PM" and due_hour == 12:
    due_hour -= 11

if current_section == "AM" and due_hour == 12:
    due_hour -= 11

if due_section == "PM" and due_hour == 12:
    due_hour -= 11

if due_section == "AM" and due_hour == 12:
    due_hour -= 11

if current_hour < due_hour:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")

if current_hour == due_hour:
    if current_minute < due_minute:
        print("True")
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are over complicating this a little bit.

> Note this is pure and without use of time and datetime libs

I would firstly convert all times to 24H clock so `9:20PM` becomes `21:20` and `9:20AM` would stay `9:20`

To do this it would be something like:

```py
if due_section == "PM" and due_hour < 12:
    due_hour += 12

if current_section == "PM" and current_hour < 12:
    current_hour += 12

# Then simply check the hour then minutes.
if due_hour < current_hour:
    print("False - Overdue by hours.")
elif due_hour == current_hour and due_minute < current_minute:
    print("False - Overdue by minutes.")
else:
    print("True - On Time.")
```

Note, this would only work for same day times.
You're question doesn't ask about crossing over midnight / handling next day deadlines.

Answer (score 0):

You're working too hard.

Let python's parsing library sweat the details for you.

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> 
>>> dt.datetime.strptime('9:58 AM', '%I:%M %p')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 58)
>>> 
>>> dt.datetime.strptime('9:58 PM', '%I:%M %p')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 21, 58)
```

Parse out times with

```
due     = dt.datetime.strptime(f"{due_hour}:{due_minute} {due_section}", "%I:%M %p")
current = dt.datetime.strptime(f"{current_hour}:{current_minute} {current_section}", "%I:%M %p")
if due < current:
    ...
```